# cant pass react state to a child after setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I'm working on reactjs project**

where I fetching data from firestore and set the app.js state to the fetched data, and I pass this state to a child of app.js to display it but it's undefined at first then it consoles the right state.

How can I make the child component render only after its props is correct?!

```
  fetchDataFromFirestore = async () => {
    let dataRefFromFirestore = database.doc('items/fruitsDataJsonFile');
    (await dataRefFromFirestore).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      let fetchedItems = snapshot.data();
      this.setState({
        fetchedItems: fetchedItems.data
      },
        console.log('DONEEE ADIING'))
    })
  }
```

Comment: In the child component render conditional `return(props.data?(<div>whatever </div>):null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a concept called "**Conditional Rendering**".

It will be like

```
    {!!this.state.fetchedItems?.length && 
<YourChildComponent fetchedItems={this.state.fetchedItems}>
```

Then, your child component will be rendered only when the state has array data.

Similarly, your child component will have props called fetchedItems with full data.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: In your code if `length` is `0` then it will render `0` on the screen

Comment: @azium , thanks for pointing out, where's my usual not-not !! haha . just added. cheers!

Comment: commonly referred to as "double-bang" https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-bang-bang-i-shot-you-down-use-of-double-bangs-in-javascript-7c9d94446054